# How to implement Integer+MyObject()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Asking just out of curiocity. I've been playing around with python, and noticed this behaviour:

1. `(2).__add__(2)` results in 4, which is totally expected;
2. `(2).__add__('a')` results in `NotImplemented` - nothing weird yet;
3. `'a'.__add__(2)` produces an exception.

But, when trying to create my own class like so:

```py
class Integer:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.val = d
    def __add__(self, i):
        return self.val+int(i)
    def __iadd__(self, i):
        self.val += int(i)
        return self
    def __int__(self):
        return self.val
```

and comparing it to `decimal.Decimal`, some weird stuff happens. They behave similarly in this case:

```py
import decimal

a = Integer(2)
a += 2
print(int(a+2))

d = decimal.Decimal(2)
d += 2
print(int(d+2))
```

However, this is not as similar: `2+d` works normally while `2+a` throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    2+a
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Integer'
```

even though `(2).__add__(a)` and `(2).__add__(d)` both produce `NotImplemented` and `a.__add__(2)` and `d.__add__(2)` work normally.
What exactly is happening with `decimal.Decimal` and how can I make this happen with my class?

Comment: `throws an exception` can you please paste it here?

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 sure

Comment: That's why [`__radd__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Implement `__radd__` too](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

```
class Integer:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.val = d

    def __add__(self, i):
        return self.val + int(i)

    def __radd__(self, i):
        return self.__add__(i)  # might be different if operation is not commutative

    def __iadd__(self, i):
        self.val += int(i)
        return self

    def __int__(self):
        return self.val


x = Integer(5) + 5
y = 5 + Integer(5)
```

Comment: How exactly does that work? Is `__radd__` called only after `__add__` returns `NotImplemented`? Are there any special cases ( `__radd__` returns `NotImplemented` or something) and, if there are, what would happen in those?

Comment: Why isn't `__radd__` documented inside `operator` module?

Comment: Re your first question: yes, it looks like reverse functions are called if the forward functions raise NotImplemented: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/de92769d473d1c0955d36da2fc71462621326f00/Objects/typeobject.c#L6387-L6388

Comment: Re your second question: because it doesn't need to have a mapping for an operator function.